# Javafx how to put shape above another shapes

Tags: java, javafx

Trying to write a snake game. I want to mark place where the snake bites itself in red ,but the snake body overlaping it.
I tried to put the shape from the head over the body with getHead().shape.toFront() command, but it didn't work. Possibly because the snake is added to paneGame.getChildren() as a list and toFront doesn't allow changing the order in which the elements list are drawn.

I solved this problem change color overlaping body part. Can somebody advise more simply solution?

```
 public class Draw extends Application {
    Pane paneGame;
    static Snake snake;

    static final public int xLField = 50;
    static final public int yLField = 53;
    static final public int yLFieldGame = 50;
    static public int sizeCell = 10;
    int speed = 100;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        paneGame = new Pane();
        borderPane.setCenter(paneGame);
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, xLField * sizeCell, yLField * sizeCell, Color.GRAY);
        setOnKey(scene);
        snake = Snake.generatedSnake();
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(speed),
                        event -> gameProcessing()));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();
        stage.setTitle("Snake");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    void gameProcessing() {
                paneGame.getChildren().clear();
                snake.move();
                if (snake.getHead().hasIntersection(snake.getBody())) {
                    snake.snakeDead();
                }
                paneGame.getChildren().addAll(snake.getBodyShapes());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    void setOnKey(Scene scene) {
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(key -> {
            if (key.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) snake.setDirection(Direction.UP);
            if (key.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) snake.setDirection(Direction.DOWN);
            if (key.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) snake.setDirection(Direction.LEFT);
            if (key.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) snake.setDirection(Direction.RIGHT);
        });
    }
}

enum Direction {
    UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT
}

public class Snake {
    private final ArrayList<Body> body;
    private Body head;
    public ArrayList<Shape> getBodyShapes() {
        ArrayList<Shape> shapeListFromBody = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Body body : this.body) {
            shapeListFromBody.add(body.getShape());
        }
        return shapeListFromBody;
    }
    public ArrayList<Body> getBody(){return body;}
    Body getHead() {
        return head;
    }

    public void move() {

           int x = head.getX();
           int y = head.getY();
            switch (direction) {
                case UP -> y -= 1;
                case DOWN -> y += 1;
                case LEFT -> x -= 1;
                case RIGHT -> x += 1;
            }
        body.add(0, new Body(x, y));
            Cell.cellPool.remove((body.get(body.size() - 1).cellId));
            body.remove(body.size() - 1);
        head = body.get(0);
    }

    public Snake() {
        direction = Direction.RIGHT;
        this.body = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            body.add(new Body(Draw.xLField/2 - i, Draw.yLFieldGame/2));
        }
        head = this.body.get(0);
    }
    private Direction direction;
    public static Snake generatedSnake(){
        return new Snake();
    }
    public void snakeDead(){
        getHead().shape.setFill(RED);
        getHead().shape.toFront();
        /*for(Body body: body){
           if(getHead().hasIntersection(body)) {
               body.shape.setFill(RED);
           }
        }*/
    }
    public void setDirection(Direction direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    static class Body extends Cell {
        private final Shape shape;

        public Body(int x, int y) {
            super(x, y);
            shape = new Rectangle(getPixelsX(), getPixelsY(), size, size);
            shape.setFill(GREEN);
        }

        public Shape getShape() {
            return shape;
        }
    }
}
public class Cell {

    int x;
    int y;
    String cellId;
    final int size = Draw.sizeCell;
    public static HashSet<String> cellPool = new HashSet<>();

    public int getPixelsX() {
        return x * size;
    }

    public int getPixelsY() {
        return y * size;
    }

    public Cell(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.cellId = x + "_" + y;
        Cell.cellPool.add(this.cellId);
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public boolean hasIntersection(Cell otherCell) {
        return otherCell != this && this.cellId.equals(otherCell.cellId);
    }

    public boolean hasIntersection(List<? extends Cell> cells) {
        for (Cell otherCell : cells) {
            if (this.hasIntersection(otherCell)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
public class Cell {

    int x;
    int y;
    String cellId;
    final int size = Draw.sizeCell;
    public static HashSet<String> cellPool = new HashSet<>();

    public int getPixelsX() {
        return x * size;
    }

    public int getPixelsY() {
        return y * size;
    }

    public Cell(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.cellId = x + "_" + y;
        Cell.cellPool.add(this.cellId);
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }


    public boolean hasIntersection(Cell otherCell) {
        return otherCell != this && this.cellId.equals(otherCell.cellId);
    }

    public boolean hasIntersection(List<? extends Cell> cells) {
        for (Cell otherCell : cells) {
            if (this.hasIntersection(otherCell)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is too much code missing to advise, consider providing a [mcve], not the whole app, but a specially coded example that demonstrates only the issue via copy/paste with no change or addition.  Theoretically `toFront()` on the node would work if all relevant nodes are siblings (that it didn't work indicates that this was not the case).  You can adjust the z co-ordinate (e.g. -1) to make it paint on top of everything regardless, but you might want to better understand what you are doing before you do that.

Comment: @jewelsea Thanks for the advice, I solved the problem using setViewOrder with -1 parameter (before I used a positive value)

Comment: With enough reputation you will be able to [answer your an question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using setViewOrder with -1 parameter (before I used a positive value)